# T-SQL Conditional WHERE clause based on result of WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'll start by saying, my question title speaks for itself, this by all means SHOULD be two selects (or nested, or w/e); But I'm stuck in a scenario where really, I can only use one select. Really.

The question is quite simple,

Lets take the following simple tables (joined)

```
T1.A  T2.B   T2.C
____________________ 
3     6     'hello'   
3    NULL   'default1'   
4    NULL   'default2'   
5     6     'jack!'
```

Basically I want to return 1 row for every distinct A containing A & B & C where B has a match in both tables (i'll expand on that below)
Simple enough, BUT if there is no match (on B) for the row(A) then I want that row to still return the default one (B=NULL)

So taking the table above I would want

```
3     6     'hello'    
4    NULL   'default2'   
5     6     'jack!'
```

My select looks like this so far, but I'm stumped as to how to get my desired result:

```
  /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT T1.A, T2.B, T2.C  
FROM [Table] T1
JOIN [Table2] T2 ON T1.D = T2.D  
WHERE T1.B = T2.B OR T2.B IS NULL
```

obviously right now the problem is that all 'default' rows are returned, i only want the T2.B IS NULL to be returned if there is no T1.B = T2.B

## *EDIT*

To Clarify, D is the identity for table 2.
B is a common column and actually is the identity of a 3rd unneeded Table (as a bunch of other columns that have nothing to do with the problem so I did not post them)

For those wanting the complete code, I'm skilled enough to sifter through whats needed and not; you do not want the complete 50 column definitions of all tables involved or the full sp with it's 6 temp tables  -_-

Thanks for everyone's help; Tim pointed it out to me with his question in the comments about B

Solution: Simply add a alternate(extra) C column and then coalesce it, put the B clause into the JOIN statement and make it a LEFT JOIN, and then re-join it on Table 2 where its NULL, so I have:

```
  /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT T1.A, T2.B, COALESCE(T2.C, T3.C) AS C  
FROM [Table] T1
LEFT JOIN [Table2] T2 ON T1.D = T2.D AND T1.B = T2.B 
JOIN [Table2] T3 ON T1.D = T3.D AND T3.B IS NULL
```

which gives me my desired result:

```
3     6     'hello'     
4    NULL   'default2' 
5     6     'jack!'
```

Comment: " I'm stuck in a scenario where really, I can only use one select." - what scenario? Why?

Comment: *I'm just hoping for ?magic?* - they  stopped providing these kind of services :D

Comment: basically I doubt I can do what I want with a single select, but if I can't I'll have to scrap the whole thing, so I'm reaching out and asking if anyone sees a way to do it that I'm not seeing right now... it's a 500 lines of legacy code scenario. Deciding to do it with multiple selects is not a viable option.

Comment: You probably can do it by joining to Table2 twice with different aliases, and choosing between the two aliases with CASE WHEN clauses.  Can you clarify what column "D" is ?  Trying to understand why you are joining on D but filtering on B before I can provide an example solution

Comment: Edit your question and show the original data.

Comment: Was about to edit question for Tim, but while writing it it hit me; *stupid me* ; I'll post my solution too, I was looking way too deep into this (or I think i have it solved and don't lol) - But thanks Tim for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that numbers can be used as aliases without being qualified!

Comment: ok that was just for clarity, if I used simple letters everywhere it wouldve gotten complicated fast. I renamed the table aliases, just for you :)

Comment: You want me to post my own answer and accept it then? Because mine does work. And Tim is the one that gave me the answer, not all the bickering about wanting real data and 500 lines of code that have nothing to do with the question. Geez, it was honestly straightforward and a pretty simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing something like this is what you are after

```
SELECT    1.A,
          COALESCE(2.B, 3.B) AS B,
          CASE 
           WHEN 2.B IS NULL THEN 3.C 
           ELSE 2.C 
          END AS C
FROM      [Table] 1
LEFT JOIN [Table2] 2
ON        1.D = 2.D AND 1.B = 2.B
LEFT JOIN [Table2] 3
ON        1.D = 3.D AND 2.B IS NULL
```

Comment: COALESCE!!! this brings it to exactly what I need!!!, Thanks for both pointing me in the right direction AND bringing that up too!!!! - so we dont have exactly the same select statement as a solution, but this IS the way to go

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `outer apply` for this:

```
SELECT t1.A, t2.B, t2.C  
FROM [Table] t1 OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 t2.*
      FROM t2
      WHERE t1.D = t2.D AND
            (t1.B = t2.B OR t2.B IS NULL)
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t1.B = t2.B THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
     ) t2;
```

The result set has one row for each row in the first table.  The columns from the second table come first from a matching row and then from the row with `NULL` values (presumably the row containing the default value).

Comment: I count two `SELECT` there - I've no idea if this is what they are claiming they can't use as they also mention "nested" or whether they are talking about two entirely different SELECT statements.